# Combining dataframes in pandas and populating with maximum values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to combine multiple data frames in pandas and I want the new dataframe to contain the maximum element within the various dataframes. All of the dataframes have the same row and column labels. How can I do this?

Example:

```
df1 = Date     A    B    C
      1/1/15   3    5    1
      2/1/15   2    4    7

df2 = Date     A    B    C
      1/1/15   7    2    2
      2/1/15   1    5    4
```

I'd like the result to look like this.

```
df =  Date     A    B    C
      1/1/15   7    5    2
      2/1/15   2    5    7
```

Comment: I think `np.where(df1 > df2, df1, df2)` should work

Comment: Is your `A` value for `2/1/15` in final `df` wrong? It should be 2 from `df1`

Comment: Why is `1` in your expected output?

Comment: Yes, sorry it should be 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.where` to return an array of the values that satisfy your boolean condition, this can then be used to construct a df:

```
In [5]:
vals = np.where(df1 > df2, df1, df2)
vals

Out[5]:
array([['1/1/15', 7, 5, 2],
       ['2/1/15', 2, 5, 7]], dtype=object)

In [6]:    
pd.DataFrame(vals, columns = df1.columns)

Out[6]:
     Date  A  B  C
0  1/1/15  7  5  2
1  2/1/15  2  5  7
```

I don't know if `Date` is a column or index but the end result will be the same.

**EDIT**

Actually just use [`np.maximum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html):

```
In [8]:
np.maximum(df1,df2)

Out[8]:
     Date  A  B  C
0  1/1/15  7  5  2
1  2/1/15  2  5  7
```

Comment: Got it, thanks again. This is my first time asking a question here.